# Middleware is a kind of proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Middlewares, like proxies, are in the middle of information, so are they theoretically similar?

If they are different, what makes them different?

Comment: Depends on your definition of middleware and your definition of proxy.

Comment: Middlewares (when talking about frameworks like Express or Connect) are more like plugins - kind of like how Adobe Photoshop has plugins or how browsers have extensions

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, there are both some similarities and some differences between a proxy and middleware.

A proxy stands between the sender and the recipient and has the option to modify a request (often adding headers) as the request goes through or it can block or deny the request.

Similarly, middleware can also modify an incoming request before it's eventual handler receives it.

But, a proxy handles raw HTTP protocol and forwards HTTP protocol to some other endpoint.

Middleware doesn't generally work at the raw HTTP protocol level.  At the point middleware gets involved, the RAW HTTP request (except perhaps for the body) has already been parsed and is available in convenient programming form.  Likewise, middleware typically has a request object where the already parsed pieces are stored and those pieces can be directly modified (such as headers) or additional properties can be added that may be useful to the eventual request handler (for example, with session managers).

A proxy will typically be an independent piece of network infrastructure that usually runs independently from the http server.  It may even be on a different part of the network such as at the gateway to another network.

Middleware, on the other hand, is inside the http server and part of the http server processing (kind of like a plug-in) and is part of the server endpoint processing.

Both proxy and middleware can perform authentication services and deny service if not properly authenticated.